# Find and replace folder and file names with Windows incompatible characters

Tags: command-line, directory, batch-rename, filename, special-characters

My Ubuntu (18.04) drive is synchronised with a Windows drive. Some of my folder and file names in Ubuntu contains characters not allowed in Windows and this causes issues during sync. I want to find these characters and either remove them from the file/folder names or replace these characters by an "x". This needs to be done recursively across the folder/directory tree.

How can I do this quickly?

Here are the characters forbidden in Windows ([modified from Christopher Oezbek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31976060/12488836)):

```
< (less than)
> (greater than)
: (colon - sometimes works, but is actually NTFS Alternate Data Streams)
" (double quote)
\ (backslash)
| (vertical bar or pipe)
? (question mark)
* (asterisk)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [`rename`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rename.ul.1.html), you need to install it first.

```
sudo apt-get install rename
```

Below is an example, you can change `*` to where your file/folder located.

```
~$ ls
'1<.txt'   3:.txt     '5\.txt'  '7??.txt'
'2>.txt'  '4"d".txt'  '6|.txt'  '8*.txt'

~$ rename -v 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]/x/g' *
1<.txt renamed as 1x.txt
2>.txt renamed as 2x.txt
3:.txt renamed as 3x.txt
4"d".txt renamed as 4xdx.txt
5\.txt renamed as 5x.txt
6|.txt renamed as 6x.txt
7??.txt renamed as 7xx.txt
8*.txt renamed as 8x.txt

~$ ls
 1x.txt   2x.txt   3x.txt   4xdx.txt  '5x.txt'   6x.txt   7xx.txt   8x.txt
```

Comment: Thanks. The files/folders to be renamed are scattered across the folder tree. How can I do this recursively across the folder/directory tree?

Comment: @JayDin you can use `find` clauses to perform that

Comment: This seems to work:
    find * -iregex '.*/.*[?<>\\:*|\"].*' -exec rename -v 's/[?<>\\:*|\"]/x/g' * {} \;

Comment: @JayDin Glad it works, please do accept the answer if you think it's useful. Thanks

Comment: I didn't know the solution is here; I skipped this post when I saw `~$ ls` in Liso's solution. His/her answer could be made more helpful if formatting is improved to make the solution easily and clearly visible.  

The following seems to also work:
`find . -depth -name '*?*' -exec rename 's/[\:*?"<>|]/x/g' {} \;`