# Rename files and folders in all sub directorys to remove character

Tags: uninstall, directory, rename

I have some files and folders that were saved in Linux on an external HDD, some of these files and folders contain the characters "::" I want to remove these characters from all files and folders on the drive as I get problems when trying to view the files in windows.

I have successfully removed them from one folder by using in terminal-

```
rename 's/:://' *::*.*
```

when in that single directory but want to do it for all files and folders on the drive, and there are many sub folders.

What can I add to the above command to make it work on all sub folders and files in the sub folders or is there a better command.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't test on phone but `locate *::*` would be the fastest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find` command to search for files and directories recursively ex.

```
find path/to/start/dir/ -depth -name '*::*.*' -exec rename 's/:://' {} +
```

The `-depth` is important if you are renaming files *and directories* (otherwise the command may "orphan" some matched files by renaming their containing directories before it has a chance to rename them). If you only wish to rename files, then you can add `-type f` and drop the `-depth`.

I recommend running the command first with `rename -n` to make sure that it is doing the right thing.

Comment: To add to this, if we wanted to remove all common characters that can cause problems such as 
/ \ : * ? " < > |
how would we do that?

Comment: @user1032409 , See if **[this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1194167/find-and-replace-folder-and-file-names-with-windows-incompatible-characters)** helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could try a recursive script. Here is something along the lines of what would work. This works on a test directory I just made that contains files and directories that contain files that are named as you describe. this script goes recursively through the entire directory tree and replaces any occurence of :: in any file names with a dot. It is set up to accept a directory or a list of directories as an argument or arguments, but it also works on a single file. Not sure that this accounts for all needed considerations or possible error scenarios though, so adjust it for what you need if you use it.

```
#!/bin/bash

function rmCols() {

    if [[ ! -e $1 ]]
    then
        usage "$1" 1
    fi

    if [[ -f $1 ]]
    then
        if [[ -w $1 ]]
        then
            rename :: . "$1"
        else
            usage "$1" 2
        fi
    elif [[ -d $1 ]]
    then
        if [[ -w $1 ]]
        then
            for THING in "$1"/*
            do
                if [[ -f $THING ]]
                then
                    rename :: . "$THING"
                elif [[ -d $THING ]]
                then
                    rmCols "$THING"
                fi
            done
        else
            usage "$1" 3
        fi
    else
        usage "$1" 4 
    fi
}

function usage() {
    echo "
Usage: 

    rmCols accepts a variable number of files and/or directories as arguments and will add the
    current date between the filename and the file type extension for all files in all directory 
    argument(s) or for any file argument(s), recursively.

Syntax:

    rmCols dirName_1 [dirName_2] [dirName_3] ......." >&2
    if [[ $2 -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo "
Error: 

    There is no such file or directory as $1, check your spelling" >&2
        exit 1
    elif [[ $2 -eq 2 ]]
    then
        echo "
Error: 

    You do not have permission to change the file $1" >&2
        exit 2
    elif [[ $2 -eq 3 ]]
    then
        echo "
Error: 

    You do not have permission to change the directory $1" >&2
        exit 3
    elif [[ $2 -eq 4 ]]
    then
        echo "
Error: 

    $1 is something other than a file or directory" >&2
        exit 4
    fi
}

shopt -s nullglob

for item in "$@"
do
    [[ -h $item ]] && continue
    rmCols "$item"
done

exit 0
```

This only changes file names not directory names, though slight modification should handle directory names too. There is likely a Linux tool that will do this without a script though, I am just not familiar with it. Although this works, I am sure there is a better solution.