# Find and remove common characters that should not be used in filenames and folders

Tags: files, directory, delete, shared-folders, rename

Following on from this question-
[Rename files and folders in all sub directorys to remove character](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1201615/rename-files-and-folders-in-all-sub-directorys-to-remove-character?noredirect=1)

I would like to remove all common characters that can cause problems such as / \ : * ? " < > |  from both filenames and folders on a HDD using command line.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl-based `rename` command accepts regular expression patterns, so you can use a [character set](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) expression `[\:*?"<>|]` (note that you can't use OR replace `/` in a Unix filename, since it's the path separation character).

Ex. given

```
$ ls fi*
 file   file1   file2   file.log  'fi:le*na<me>'   file.txt
```

then

```
$ rename -n 's/[\:*?"<>|]//g' *
rename(fi:le*na<me>, filename)
```